# Chrome doesn't load untrusted SSL content in iframe

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, ssl

Whenever I try to load a page whose SSL certificate is untrusted inside an `iframe`, Chrome 29 displays error page inside instead. Error code is ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE.

For the same scenario, Firefox displays SSL warning in iframe with an option to ignore it.

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Glpdv

How can I force Chrome to display either a page itself or a dismissable SSL warning?

Comment: Serve the page via HTTP? An untrusted SSL cert is only marginally more secure.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I need to support user-specified pages, and they might be insecure-SSLed

Comment: Any progress on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Open the iframe content in new window and accept cert.
Then you will be able to open this also in iframe.

Answer (score 0):

This problem cause while ssl integration not completed properly. Some details available here : https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/connection-untrusted-error-message

If you are using amazon and godaddy server combination let me know I can provide the working guide to fix this issue.